# Filtering out numeric indexes from an array with javascript

Tags: javascript

This is the code i have written to filter out Numeric values from an array, but it is returning the complete array. I am not able to find out the problem in my code. Please help me i am stuck...

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>html demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    arr = ["apple", 5, "Mango", 6];
    function filterNumeric(arrayName){
        var i = 0;
        var numericArray=[];
        for (i; i <arrayName.length;i++){
            if (typeof(arrayName[i] === 'number')) {
                numericArray+=arrayName[i];
            }
        }
        return numericArray;
    }

    var filter = filterNumeric(arr);
    alert(filter);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo in the `typeof` check:

```
if (typeof(arrayName[i]) === 'number') {
//                    ^^^ close the parentheses here
//                                 ^^^ not there
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript arrays have [a built-in filtering method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
var arr = ["apple", 5, "Mango", 6];
var filtered = arr.filter(function(item) { return (typeof item === "number")});
console.log(filtered); // Array [5,6]
```

As for your original code, beware that [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) is an operator, not a function, so

```
if (typeof(foo === "whatever")) {
    // ...
}
```

is equivalent to

```
if (typeof some_boolean_value) {
    // ...
}
```

which evaluates to

```
if ("boolean") {
    // ...
}
```

which will always be true, this is why you ended up with the whole content with no filtering whatsoever.

Also note that the `+=` operator is not overloaded for arrays, you will end up with a string concatenation of the remaining values:

```
var foo = [];
var bar = [1,2,3,4];
foo += bar[2];
console.log(foo); // "3"
console.log(typeof foo); // "string"
```

you must use the [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method instead:

```
var foo = [];
var bar = [1,2,3,4];
foo.push(bar[2]);
console.log(foo); // Array [3]
console.log(typeof foo); // "object"
```